# How to change the time in the second timepicker dialog in the same activity?

Tags: android, timepicker

Hi am using two time pickers in the same activity.my requirement is first timepicker will show current time and the second one will show the (current hour +1) but my problem is second one doesnot shows the (current hour +1) it's also displays current time. here is my code

```
  if(v.equals(stimeimage))
  {
   stime=true;
   myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); 
  }
  if(v.equals(etimeimage))
  {   
   etime=true;
   myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);       
  }
  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener
                     = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
 {
  if(monthOfYear+1<10)
   datetext = String.valueOf(year) + "-0"+ String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + "-"+ String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
  else
   datetext = String.valueOf(year) + "-"+ String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) + "-"+ String.valueOf(dayOfMonth); 
  Log.e("datetext",datetext);

   myHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   if(etime)
    myHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+1; 
   Log.e("mhour",""+myHour);
   myMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);    
   }
  };

  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
  {
      AlertDialog myDialog = null;
   switch(id){
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:{
    myDialog= new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);
    break;
    }
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:{
            myDialog= new TimePickerDialog(this,myTimeSetListener,myHour, myMinute, false);
            break;
    }

   }
   return myDialog;
  }
```

when i pressed the second timepicker in the log it shows the (currenthour+1) but it displays current hour..Please help me what the solution..

i googled a lot and didn't find any solution..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(currentHour+1);
```

you add it programatically in oncreate method

Comment: am not used any time picker in xml.created in programatically then how can u change?

Comment: Could u know how to change hour in timepicker dynamically ?

Comment: myDialog= new TimePickerDialog(this,myTimeSetListener,YOUR HOUR WITHIN 24,YOUR MINUTE WITHIN 60 , false);

Comment: yes in the above code myHour is within 24 and myminute is within 60